# Ionic 2: circle progress bar while holding

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, progress-bar

I would like to implement something like this:

When a user taps and hold an element , a circular progress bar would appear around the point being pressed. Say it has to be held for 2 seconds to fill up the circle, then an event is triggered. If the user releases earlier than 2 seconds, nothing happens.

Comment: Is it inside `*ngFor`? on a button press? Provide some code.

Comment: Share what you have so far, its earlier to help then

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say exactly what you want to achieve without any code but ionic does have [gestures](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#gestures) that you can use.

There is one specifically called `pressed` which can be used like so

```
<ion-card (pressed)="pressedEvent($event)">
  <ion-item>

  </ion-item>
</ion-card>
```

Which would trigger `pressedEvent`. In your component you could get some info from the triggered event or also pass in information to be used. So if it was in a

```
*ngFor="let items of items;let idx=index" (pressed)="pressedEvent($event,item,idx)"
```

And then in your component

```
pressedEvent(ev,item,idx){
   // details on press event
   console.log(ev);
   // details on current item in loop being pressed
   console.log(item);
   // index of current item being pressed for specific array based manipulation 
   console.log(idx); 
}
```